# Eclipse doesn't find my already running Android emulators

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

*Configuration*

Os: OSX

IDE: Eclipse Juno

I don't know why but when I try to run again my Android app, the **"Android Device Chooser"** frame opens but my emulators are not shown in **"Choose a running Android device"** section. What should I do ?

Comment: Does API level of both the emulator and application is same.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj Not exactly the same, but the API level of my emulator is higher than my project's.

Comment: as temporary solution you can restart adb ... there is a triangle button in Devices tab (View Menu) last option should be reset adb

Comment: @Rob No problem. it should work though, try restarting ADB.

Comment: sometimes it happens... I was not able to fix it.

Comment: startTaskManager --> processes --> kill adb

Comment: Thanks for your answers, restarting ADB was the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto the DDMS view and try resetting the ADB as shown---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I have this problem : I've created 4 different emulators, visible in the Android Devices Manager, but I can't see any of them in this "Devices" window... which is empty.

Comment: Are the emulators Up and Running?

Answer (score 1):

- Please check the required API levels of the application and than on the device.
- Try to run following commands in terminal that will renew the adb server state :

  adb kill-server
  adb start-server
- You can try to use [adb over the wifi](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1685736) and than no cables will needed.